# Is this possible to limited the variable scope in swift?

Tags: swift, variables

For example, I need a valuable which is an `Int`, but I limited it can only set from 1-10. Is this features build in in swift? Except from override the setter. Is this possible to do so?

btw, what is this feature named? I remember I come across some languages got this features, but I don't recall the name of that languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for an [enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID146). It allows you to set a range of values (not strictly numbers though), which are allowed as input. Do something like this:

```
enum NumsTill10 {
    case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
}
```

And to set it as a variable:

```
let number:NumsTill10 = NumsTill10.1
```

Or even

```
let number:NumsTill10 = .1
```

And then you can do:

```
if number == .7 {
    //It's 7!
}
```